# Elastic Searching across all entire model instead of user's records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have the following form:

```
    <%= form_tag(messages_path, method: :get, class: "form-inline", role: 'search', remote: true) do %>
      <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%">
        <%= text_field_tag :term,
                           params[:term],
                           id: 'messages_search',
                           autocomplete: :off,
                           class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Which relies on the following section of the controller:

```
search = params[:term].present? ? params[:term] : nil
@messages = Message.where("recipient_id IS NOT NULL").where(user_id: current_user.id).or(Message.where(recipient_id: current_user.id)).search(search)
```

end

I would like to limit the scope of search to the current_user's messages where he is recipients (`recipient_id: current_user.id`) or sender (`user_id: current_user.id`), but for now the search goes across the entire message database. it does not seem to be even relying on the constraints that I put in the controller.

It seems that the first part of the query checking the sender and recipient is totally being ignored. It is returning me key word found in other people's messasges.

Do you guys see what I am missing please ?

Comment: are you using any gem for elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes indeed, i use gem 'searchkick'

Answer (score 0):

change this to `search = params[:term].present? ? params[:term] : nil` from `search = params[:term].present? ? params[:term] : "*"`

and change your query to this:

```
Message.search params[:term].to_s where: { _not: { recipient_id: nil }, _or: [{ user_id: current_user.id }, { recipient_id: current_user.id }] }
```